# Where to deploy Java XMPP server application?

Tags: deployment, server, cloud, xmpp, console-application

I have XMPP serwer written in Java SE using Smack 4.3.0. It is command line application.
It is working locally. Now I want to deploy it on the some kind of web container in the Internet. 
I do not really know how to do it and where I can upload my serwer app. 
I found some cloud like HEROKU etc. but all the hosting places's tutorial are about Java Web App with Servlet etc. 
I just want to run my CMD app on the Internet.
Also I have MySql DB which I want to run on the same container.
Can you provide some URL where can I do it?
Or maybe my approach are bad...
But there must be place for this kind of app. What about simple application handling WebSocket? Where are they running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can recommend to try [Digital Ocean](https://www.digitalocean.com/), it needs some manual work but it's very easy. I like it for their simplicity and also because they have lots of ready-to-go guides for newbies

Step-by-Step Guide:

1. [Create Digital Ocean account](https://cloud.digitalocean.com/registrations/new) or sign in if you have an existing one
2. Create a Droplet from the Digital Ocean Control Panel. Droplets are something similar to virtual machines. I recommend to try with a very basic shape which costs only 5$ per month. You can easily scale it after in a single click. I also recommend to choose an Ubuntu image with no additional software for your droplet — Ubuntu is an OS that is super easy in setup if you do not have much experience.
3. Once droplet is ready — you need to perform an [Initial Server Setup](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/initial-server-setup-with-ubuntu-18-04). There are a few configuration steps that you should take early on as part of the basic setup. This will increase the security and usability of your server and will give you a solid foundation for subsequent actions.
4. [Install MySQL server](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-mysql-on-ubuntu-16-04)
5. [Install Java](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-java-with-apt-get-on-ubuntu-16-04)
6. Put your app source code into server (via git or via **scp** command)
7. Simply run it in background - **nohup java -jar myapp.jar &**
8. Now you can check your java app process: **ps aux | grep myapp**

Additional stuff:

- Register and add a domain to you site, e.g. *example.com*. To set up a domain name, you need to do two things. First, you need to purchase a domain name from a domain name registrar. Second, you need to set up DNS records for your domain by using a DNS hosting service. This [DNS Quickstart guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/docs/networking/dns/quickstart/) will explain it in details.
- It’s also good to setup HTTPS for you site. The following [How To Install an SSL Certificate from a Commercial Certificate Authority](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-an-ssl-certificate-from-a-commercial-certificate-authority) guide will explain it in details.

Comment: It is working :) Thank you very much for that tutorial in the post :) Now my app working. I had some issue with maven but I manage do resolve it. Only DB import have to be done. Thanks one more time.

Comment: @wlodek14a great to hear it! So you can upvote my answer if it’s good for you